# Press a button with RSelenium in R. Web scraping Google Play

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-play, rselenium

I am trying to scrape all app reviews on Google Play. The problem is that after loading the reviews page scroll down 4 times, the "Show more" button appears, but I don't know how to press it and run again 4 more times and so on until you reach the bottom of the page.

My "scroll down" code is as follows. He put it to load but it doesn't work, since after scrolling down 4 times the "Show more" button appears and I don't know how to press it in the code.

```
    #Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
  url <- list('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&showAllReviews=true')

  # starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
  selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
  shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
  remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
  remDr$open()

  # go to website
  remDr$navigate(url)

  
  replicate(1000,
          {
            # scroll down
            webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
            webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
            # wait
            Sys.sleep(4)
          })
 
  
  morereviews <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".RveJvd.snByac")
  # click button
  morereviews$clickElement()
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to use the `class name` selector.

This it works for me.

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser= 'firefox', port = 4551L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]] 
url1 <- 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&showAllReviews=true'
remote_driver$navigate(url1)

#You can custom the range of the for if you want

    for (i in 1:10) {
    replicate(4, #4 is the correct value of the scroll in this example
              {
                # scroll down
                webElem <- remote_driver$findElement("css", "body")
                webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
                # wait
                Sys.sleep(4)
              })
      
    Sys.sleep(2) 
    remote_driver$findElement(using = 'class name', value = 'CwaK9')$clickElement()
    
    }
```

If you want to implement the tryCatch function about the "show more', below a possible solution.

```
  replicate(4, 
           {
            webElem <- remote_driver$findElement("css", "body")
            webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
            Sys.sleep(4)
            tryCatch(expr = { 
                  remote_driver$findElement(using = 'class name', value = 
                 'CwaK9')$clickElement()
              },  
              error = function(e){
                       message("no find")
                                  }
                    )             
              })
```

Comment: Great! This has helped me. However, when I press the button, I must tell the code to go back down the web page and the same button that it must press appears again and so on until I reach the end of the page. 

Therefore I have chosen to put the same code several times (next comment). 

However, I get the following error:
`Error: 'Driver info: driver.version: unknown' does not exist in current working directory ('C: / Users / Desktop / Google Play')`

What does it mean? How can I solve that?

Comment: This code:  `replicate(10,
          {
            # scroll down
            webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
            webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
            # wait
            Sys.sleep(4)
          })
 
  
  morereviews <- remDr$findElement(using = 'class name', value = 'CwaK9')
  # click button
  morereviews$clickElement()`

Comment: This error could be about that you don't find the botton 'show more'. I update my answer and with a for loop and with the correct dimention of the scroll you can avoid the problem. 
I suggest you to implement I tryCath (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625579/rselenium-dialog-box/65629177#65629177) to to avoid possible errors.

Comment: You have to fix the time of the scroll ( as I did in the answer) to avoid the error about the 'show more' button

Comment: Great! I have used the improved option that you have given, but the problem that I do not know very well how to implement the tryCath command. Could you help me implement it? Should I indicate what error it is? I have chosen to put a high number in the loop, so that it can reach the end of the web page and once it reaches the end, when it returns the error, the code can continue.
So I have implemented the tryCath command but it doesn't work for me (in the following comment)

Comment: `    for (i in 1:500) {
      tryCatch(expr = {  
        replicate(4,
                  {
                    # scroll down
                    webElem <- remote_driver$findElement("css", "body")
                    webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
                    # wait
                    Sys.sleep(4)
                  })
        Sys.sleep(2) 
        remote_driver$findElement(using = 'class name', value = 'CwaK9')$clickElement()
      }, 
      error = function(e){  # Specifying error message
        message("There was an error message.")
      }) 
    }`

Comment: TryCatch function has a big power. In my answer is just an example.